Burnt PETG extrusions


I printed this model using 250 °C nozzle temperature using PETG. I also set the extrusion multiplier to 80 % so I know it's not caused by over-extrusion.
The printer is SV06 Plus
What could cause the burnt filament?

It turns out I have a leak in the nozzle. The problem goes away after I disassembled the nozzle, cleaned it and tightened it.

Good to hear! Going forward, I have found that you can mitigate a leak in the nozzle of the SV06 without disassembling. As filament residue can accumulate around the nozzle, leaks can follow. Heat up the nozzle and use a small wire brush or a nozzle cleaning needle to gently clean away any buildup.
Note that poor quality or inconsistent filament can cause extrusion issues, including leaks. Try using a different, high-quality filament to see if the problem persists.
You could also check that the extruder is properly calibrated. If it's over-extruding, it can lead to a leak. Calibrate the extruder steps/mm to ensure the right amount of filament is being extruded.

A leak doesn't go away with cleaning, it is a physical defect that has to be addressed by tightening up the hotend assembly.  Note that the OP was testing at a flow modifier of 0.8, so leaking (as you are referring to it; you might better be calling that material pickup) cannot happen. This reads as a generic answer, possibly written by or with the help of an assistant that it doesn't appear to answer the question. The last 2 paragraphs are not applicable in this question since the OP is clearly under extruding as can be seen in the images.
